# Segmentation fault while using function pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

I get a segmentation fault when I declare a function pointer before main()
and assign it with the address of a function inside main. What is the actual problem that occurs if the function pointer is declared before main()??

The code is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void fun1(char *str)
{
    printf("%s",str);
}

void (* funptr)(char *);

int main()
{

    char msg1[10]="Hi";
    char msg2[10]="Hello";
    pthread_t pid1, pid2;

    funptr=&fun1;

    pthread_create(&pid1,NULL,(void *)(*funptr),(void *)msg1);
    pthread_create(&pid1,NULL,(void *)(*funptr),(void *)msg2);

    pthread_join(pid1,NULL);
    pthread_join(pid2,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas when I declare `funptr` inside `main()`, it gives me the proper output. Would like to know what exactly is the issue.

The problem was with the thread id. I had used the same thread id "pid1" for both the threads and I was trying to join "pid2" also which resulted in segmentation fault. Following is the rectified code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void fun1(char *str)
{
    printf("%s",str);
}

 void (* funptr)(char *);

int main()
{

    char msg1[10]="Hi";
    char msg2[10]="Hello";
    pthread_t pid1, pid2;

    funptr=&fun1;

    pthread_create(&pid1,NULL,(void *)(*funptr),(void *)msg1);
    pthread_create(&pid2,NULL,(void *)(*funptr),(void *)msg2);
    pthread_join(pid1,NULL);
    pthread_join(pid2,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pthread_create have same pid's hence the crash.

Comment: And the function and pointer are wrong regardless. They should match `void* (*)(void*)`. Stop casting and declare your function and pointer correctly.

Answer (score 3):

`funptr` is already a function pointer. To cast it to `void *`, all you need is `(void *)funptr`. You are required to have the third argument of type `void *(*) (void *)`, not cast your function to `void*`. See [pthread_create documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)

As Santhosh has written in the comments, the reason for the `SIGSEGV` is that `pthread_create()` is given as argument pointer to the same `pthread_t`.

Comment: "But you are not required to cast your function to void*" - He's casting to `void*` to circumvent the otherwise-type-checked failure to compile because `void (*funptr)(char*)` does not match the *proper* function type required by `pthread_create`, `void * (*)(void*)`.  The function and pointer should be corrected and *all* of the unneeded casts removed, [like this](http://pastebin.com/2USqJVhb)

Comment: yes the function should be of type `void *(*) (void *)`. But `msg1` and `msg2` must be cast to `void *`.

Comment: No, they don't. The linked code in my prior comment will compile as-is with a standard C compiler on any pthread-supported platform.

Comment: @WhozCraig see [pthread_create() man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html). The last argument is expected to be of type `void*`, not `char*`

Comment: I'm aware of the requirements of `phread_create`. No cast is required because they already *implicitly* cast to `void*` (as does every other data pointer type).

Answer (score 0):

```
pthread_create(&pid1,NULL,(void *)(*funptr),(void *)msg1);
pthread_create(&pid1,NULL,(void *)(*funptr),(void *)msg2);
```

In both the thread create you are using pid1.

pthread_join(pid2,NULL); 
pid2 is nothing but holding a garbage value...